# Got an error about existence a reference type in both dll after convert asp.net web form to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

Recently I change a big project from asp.net Web form to MVC 4. every thing is ok , I change some codes , and reconfigure my Web.Config file. but I got an error about existence a reference type in tow dlls

I use something like this in all over of aspx files in my project \

```
<td>
    <%= Resources.Resouce.AResource %>
</td>
```

Now after change (From web form to MVC) I got more than 2000 errors that Resource does not exists in some pages.so I changed the `Custome Tool Namespace` of my resources to `Resources` , so the project build successfully . but now I get another error

```
 CS0433: The type 'Resources.Resource' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4fbef14f\4d273162\assembly\dl3\bd8e90ff\dc59fc0b_ffd2ce01\LHW1-WebSite.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4fbef14f\4d273162\App_GlobalResources.isqs-re9.dll'
```

As the first solution I clean the solution , but the problem did not resolved 
As the second solution , I set `batch="false"` attribute in compilation tag in web.config. But still the error did not resolved

Is there any one to help me out  there ?!

thanks

Comment: Delete the contents of your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder and try it again

Comment: Make sure that the DLL doesn't exist twice, or that the DLL / class doesn't exist in the \bin folder as well as somewhere else in the solution.